# Contents Transfer Not Available Now, Sony A6000

Tags: c#, api, sdk, camera, sony

I've got Sony A6000 camera with the latest firmware(3.20) and latest Smart Remote Control application (4.30). I've been trying to write application for transferring images, but faced with issues.

I can't switch camera function to Contents Transfer mode.

Repro steps:

1. Run Smart Remote Control app on my camera;
2. Sucesfully connect device to camera via WI-FI;
3. Discover the camera with parameter ST=urn:schemas-sony-com:service:ScalarWebAPI:1;
4. Receive response Location http://ip:port/scalarwebapi_dd.xml *(instead mentioned in doc http://ip:port/dd.xml)*;
5. Parsed scalarwebapi_dd.xml contains *guide*, *accessControl* and *camera* services (instead mentioned in doc *camera*, *system* and *avContent*);
6. Request with getAvailableApiList method return the following:

   > getVersions, getMethodTypes, getApplicationInfo, getAvailableApiList, getEvent, startRecMode, stopRecMode.
7. Successfully run request with "startRecMode" method;
8. "getAvailableApiList" result doesn't contain "*getCameraFunction*" and
   "*setCameraFunction*"
9. "getCameraFunction" return the following result:

   > {"id":1,"error":[1,"Not Available Now"]}

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Smart Remote 4.30 should give you the `avContent` services. I had an older version that had the same `guide, accessControl, camera` but after I updated it had the `avContent` service.

You can also try using `getEvent` to troubleshoot the camera status. This could shed some light into why the services aren't available.

Comment: I'd installed the latest version of Smart Remote recently but there weren't any changes. Unfortunately, it has the same guide, accessControl, camera as it was before.